# How to change layout for all items in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-view

I have a RecyclerView. In adapter I have a boolean flag to determine which of layout should be used for all items:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {

    private boolean mIsSecondModeEnabled;

    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(mIsSecondModeEnabled ?
         R.layout.layout_second_mode_item :
         R.layout.layout_first_mode_item, parent, false);
        return new MyHolder(view);
    }

    public void setModeEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mIsSecondModeEnabled = enabled;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work completely right. When I call `setModeEnabled(true)` some items showing with `layout_first_mode_item` layout.

How to achieve it?

Comment: try changing mIsSecondModeEnabled to static

Comment: @sreejithvs, no, it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`onCreateViewHolder()` will be called, when there are no `ViewHolder`s in the pool of already created `ViewHolder`s. In this callback you specify what view you want `RecyclerView` to create for you.

`onCreateViewHolder()` will not necessarily be called after you have performed `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Instead `onBindViewHolder()` will be triggered. This is the place where you should update your view.

Override [`getItemViewType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) and return the layout id depending on your use case:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(final int position) {
    return mIsSecondModeEnabled ? R.layout.my_layout_1 : R.layout.my_layout_2;
}
```

Create 2 `ViewHolder` classes for those two layouts and from `onCreateViewHolder()` return appropriate `ViewHolder` depending on the `viewType` parameter of `onCreateViewHolder()` callback.

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if(viewType == R.layout.my_layout_1) {
        // create FirstViewHolder
    } else if (viewType == R.layout.my_layout_2) {
        // create SecondViewHolder
    }
    // return created ViewHolder
}
```

Then in `onBindViewHolder()` callback setup your views.